# A generic "filter" in Java

Tags: java, generics, sorting, rowfilter

I am trying to implement a generic filter of various classes of data based on a generic range. In the first iteration, this is for a JTable, where we know the name of the column and the class of data within the column. In this case, the filter view looks like:

ColumnTitle   comboBox: is/is not   comboBox: =, >, < , between  textBox min, textBox max

Where the table columns may be String, double, int, etc. as specified in an XML builder, and there may be multiple rows of these to filter based on other columns. [Obviously many of these exist in the world.]

I want to tie this to the RowFilters basically by using a `Range` class that looks like:

```
public class Range<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

T low;
T high;

public Range(T aLow, T aHigh) {
    low = aLow;
    high = aHigh;
}

public boolean includes(T value) {
    boolean result = true;
    if ((getLow() != null) && (getLow().compareTo(value) > 0)) {
         return false;
    }

    if ((getHigh() != null) && (getHigh().compareTo(value) < 0)) {
         return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public T getLow() {
    return low;
}

public void setLow(T low) {
    this.low = low;
}

public T getHigh() {
    return high;
}

public void setHigh(T high) {
    this.high = high;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Range = ").append(low).append(" to ").append(high);
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

My idea is to essentially (not real code below) build lists of:

```
class Filter { 
    Range<?> range;
    String name;
    Class<?> filterClass;
}
```

Do the class comparison in the individual filter view (or controller) and then translate these into `RowFilter` when they need to be applied.

The code base that I am working in has 100's of statements, which I simply abhor, like:
`if (bob instanceof Person)` ...

In trying to avoid that, I am hitting problems with generics and class casting.

Is this an unavoidable issue with generic type erasure?
If so, is there some decent workaround that avoids class testing scattered everywhere?

Unfortunately I cannot:
- Use Guava or anything other than Java (6 even).
- Redo the entire table builder which is XML based.
- Use a database

There must be many application where one has a table or database and does not know the data description at code compile time?

Comment: Generics in java are for specifying things that you know at compile time.  If you're not learning the information until runtime when you load the XML, you will not be able to escape type casts and the associated warnings.  You can clean up the API so it's prettier, but under the hood all that 'instanceof' stuff has to happen in some way.

Comment: What does the `Class` in `Filter` do?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing a bunch of filter code, you can filter things at the `TableModel` level using [`TableRowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html)

> An implementation of RowSorter that provides sorting and filtering using a TableModel.

and just implement a generic [`RowFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) as you describe.

Erasure shouldn't enter into it though instead of requiring things to implement `Comparable` in a way that is suitable to end-user sorting (which might need to be locale sensitive) I would take a `Comparator<? super T>` instead and let that sort values.  That way, you can also handle `null`s consistently.

Comment: I am trying to build a generic GUI to create the RowFilter. I also need to be able to use the same GUI tied to a different data model which would not use a JTable.
As far as the comparator, are you perhaps suggesting passing a comparator instead of the class of data to be sorted? 
How would one also cast the limit values that would be entered in the JTextField? For example, if the data type is supposed to be Integer, the GUI (or controller) should reject non-integer strings.

Comment: @user1777892, I don't see how passing the class of data to be sorted helps you at all, so yes, I would pass a comparator instead.  On parsing a string from a text field, I would pass an `interface Parser<T> { T parse(String s) throws ParseException; }` or something similar.